# Im trying to retrieve data from api call in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, request

This is the request function
however, when trying to call it somewhere in the app an error pops "list is not a subtype of Future"

the data I'm receiving is as follows:  `{"data":[{"name":},{"name":}]}`

I want to iterate through the value of "data" to display the names in a list

```dart
Future<Request> getRequests() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3000/wallet');
  http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return requestFromJson({'"balanceResponse"': ((response.body))}.toString());
  } else
    throw Exception(response.statusCode);
}
```

Comment: Can you include `requestFromJson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// To parse this JSON data, do

//     final myModel = myModelFromJson(jsonString);

```
import 'dart:convert';

MyModel myModelFromJson(String str) => MyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String myModelToJson(MyModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MyModel {
    MyModel({
        this.data,
    });

    List<Datum> data;

    factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyModel(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.name,
    });

    String name;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

Refer https://app.quicktype.io/ this will help you in creating model classes and parser.

Answer (score 1):

i think u have to use this:

```
Future<List<Request>> getRequests() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3000/wallet');
  http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return requestFromJson({'"balanceResponse"': ((response.body))}.toString());
  } else
    throw Exception(response.statusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample `GET` method `API` call

```
callAPI() async {
  String login = "sunrule";
  String pwd = "api";
  Uri url = Uri.parse(
      "http://vijayhomeservices.in/app/api/index.php?apicall=login&login=$login&password=$pwd");
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final body = json.decode(response.body);
    util.prints(body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Server Error !");
  }
}
```